# Is there any way to enable paging and editing in FormView if there is no DataSourceId?

Tags: c#, datasource, formview

So, I have FormView on my website. I also made layers for my business and data layer, so with simple function FetchAll I'm getting BindingList which I'm binding on FormView later with:

```
FormView.DataSource = FetchAll();
FormView.DataBind();
```

The problem occurs when I'd like to allow paging and editing which can be easily allowed when I have DataSourceId set up on FormView. But like this, without ObjectDataSource set up on DataSourceId, I can't find automatic way to allow paging or editing. Do I really need to do it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should have searched more before asking questions. There is easy way - with property "AllowPaging". Didnd't see it for immediately.